# Multiple WooCommerce Session for one user

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

I built a B2B online ordering system using WooCommerce. All users have multiple staff members to handling the order and they prefer to have one account for their company so it would be easier for them to check the order history.

I customised the checkout function to allow only one products for an order and created multiple custom fields for checkout.

The problem is that WooCommerce Cart session is shared across devices so the orders will overwrite each other if more than one staff place orders at the same time. Is there any way to make the Cart session independent across devices?

Answer (score 0):

No.
I used to fight another situation which deals the same session sharing: for example, add product to cart and go to checkout, and on another tab add another product to cart and go to checkout. 
Try to switch between tabs and change the shipping country or state, the order summary will be equal on both tabs.
They should user different usernames, or place it as guests, or not creating orders at the same time (maybe add a note at the top of the website that another order is being built at the same moment)